# Problem with .whereField and Int during a Firestore request

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

The problem is: `.whereField("likes", isGreaterThan : 0)` does not work in the function below . I don't understand why because `.whereField ("likes",isEqualTo : 0)` works.

Does anyone has an explanation for that?

```
func fecthUserLikedTweets(forUid uid: String, completion:@escaping([Tweet]) -> Void) {
        
    Firestore.firestore().collection("tweets")
        .whereField ("likes",isGreaterThan : 0)
    .whereField("uid",isEqualTo:uid)
    .getDocuments { (snapshot, _ ) in
        guard let document = snapshot?.documents else {return}
        
        let tweets = document.compactMap ({try? $0.data(as: Tweet.self)})
            completion(tweets.sorted(by:{ $0.timestamp.dateValue() > $1.timestamp.dateValue() }))
            
        }    
}
```

[image: Console]

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a screenshot from the Firestore console of a document that you expect to be returned by the query?

Comment: Have you confirmed with print statements that the data itself (the `[String: Any]` dictionary) from Firestore is wrong and not the parsing of the data? In other words, if you removed the entire compact map task and just printed the documents out one by one that the documents you expected to get are indeed missing?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing a necessary composite index for the query.

For a query only consisting of equality checks (`isEqualTo`), Firestore can fulfill them based on the single-field indexes that it generates by default.

Once you use a relational operator (`>`, `<`, etc) you need to add an additional [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#composite_indexes) to your database with the exact fields that your query uses.

The easiest way to add such an index is to catch and log errors in your code, and then find the URL in the error message to create the index.